# Magento2 Inventory Listing per store view?

Tags: magento2, database

I have a multisite magento 2.2.5 and trying to list out each sku that has less then a specific inventory but trying to list them out per store view.

Below is my sql

```
SELECT catalog_product_entity.entity_id, catalog_product_entity.sku, cataloginventory_stock_item.qty FROM catalog_product_entity, cataloginventory_stock_item
                        where catalog_product_entity.entity_id = cataloginventory_stock_item.product_id AND qty < 250"
```

how do I edit it to look at a specific store view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use only the Default stock and one website in your setup you will not be able to make a difference for the a product's stock in different store views.

That's because Magento keeps the stock per website. So if you have multiple stores and/or storeviews for the same website they will usually share the stock for a common prodcut by default.

If you use different websites with their own stock you can use the stock_id attribute in cataloginventory_stock_item to filter your selection.